# PowerShell module can only be imported via shortcut?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, import-module

Installed the Azure Active Directory Module and it works just fine; but only when I launch PowerShell using the shortcut created by the install wizard. Can't figure out why this works like a champ when going via cmd.exe, but not when I attempt to import the module directly from a PowerShell session.

Using the shortcut normally or pasting its command string into a traditional command prompt successfully loads the module:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -NoExit -Command "Import-Module MSOnline"
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.1.166.0  MSOnline                            {Add-MsolAdministrativeUnitMember, Add-MsolFo...
```

However, opening a PowerShell session 'as Administrator' and attempting to import the same module, on the same system, throws this error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Import-Module MSOnline
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files
(x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MSOnline\1.1.166.0\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll' or one of its
dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Why do I have to walk this one particular module through the old-timey Command Prompt in order to get it to function, when every other module I import without any problem?

Comment: You are trying to load a 32-bit DLL, make sure that you are using 32-bit powershell.

Comment: This is interesting. Up until this point, I had been using 32-bit PowerShell (i.e. "PowerShell (x86)"). But just for the sake of experimentation I opened a 64-bit PowerShell session and tried the Import-Module process again. It worked. So I guess the module is 64-bit and the shortcut was using a 32-bit command prompt to invoke a 64-bit PowerShell session?